# Is gradually growing swap usage an indicator for a memory leak?

Tags: windows, memory, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, memory-leaks

I’m trying to understand whether I have a memory leak on my server (Windows Server 2012R2). The server has 48 GB RAM and was designed to run only a DBMS (a SQL Server 2014) but there are also other tools like Symantec Endpoint Protection, FireEye and some monitoring tools/services installed. It is currently configured to reserve 42 GB to DBMS leaving 6 GB to OS and other services. There were out-of-memory errors when only 4 GB were reserved for OS and other services, which disappeared after I increased this to 6 GB. High RAM usage itself is normal for a SQL Server machine, as SQL Server buffers the data in RAM.

What worries me is that swap usage (performance counter Paging File->Usage) is gradually increasing in the last 2 months currently reaching 15 % of 24 GB (size of the swap file). I’m not sure whether this is fine because Windows puts stuff in swap even under normal conditions or is it an indicator that 6 GB also won’t be enough after some time. On the chart below green line is RAM usage (spikes down when I restarted the SQL Server and rapidly gets up again) and yellow is the swap usage since mid-May.

Swap usage image

[image: Swap usage image]

What I have done:

1. Dumped the performance counters “Process->Private bytes”. Nothing really suspicious here. TOP10 in MBs are (total 44711 MB):

   - sqlserver      41322
   - xagt#5        504
   - ccsvchst      316
   - splunkd       285
   - ccsvchst#1        260
   - monitoringhost    233
   - xagt#1        151
   - monitoringhost#1  129
   - healthservice         116
   - svchost#4         110
2. Tried to restart individual services (SQL Server, xagt/Fireeye, splunkd). This had no effect on the swap usage.
3. Tried to get more information using tools RAMMap from Sysinternals and VMMap as I suspected that some process leaks memory through memory mapped files, which don’t count to private bytes.

   RAMMap reports following (unfortunately the files under File Summary/File Details are only adding up to less than 300 MB used though 2659 MB reported as active for mapped files):

   Screenshot from rammap

   [image: Screenshot from rammap]

I have another server with the same tools installed, but 96 GB RAM and 16 GB swap. RAM usage is below 50 %, but swap usage is also (almost) continuously increasing currently at 28 %.

Swap usage on another server

[image: Swap usage on another server]

Is this kind of behavior normal? If not, how I can find the problematic process?

Comment: Swap space should be at least equal to the size of RAM, ideally double.

Comment: Did you check the if the difference between virtual memory and used memory is growing? If you see only the virtual memory growing it means that the OS is reserving more memory for some processes. If it is the used memory that keeps growing it might be a leak.

Comment: @deep64blue well, _ideally_ the size of RAM is such that you never even need swap. But _ideal_ is seldom what one should go for. Instead you should use whatever works well and is cost-effective.

Answer (score 8):

Backing swap storage is a parameter that is consultable.
When it's sufficient then over-commitment of memory is not required.
My previous answer was not the real explanation.

The conclusion is then that the poster has a real memory
leak that doesn't show up in the tools.
This usually means that the leak is in Windows or some third-party
driver.

Such leaks are very hard to find, and when found they are often
in proprietary code that cannot be modified.

As the leak in this case is very small with no performance hit,
the problem is mostly just an annoyance. It can be fixed by
a reboot every so often. In the poster's case this can even be
something as infrequent as once a month.

---

Previous answer when less information was available:

You are apparently under the impression that the swap space is only used
when Windows (or any OS) runs out of RAM. This is far from the case.

The OS must be ready to swap out processes when RAM is exhausted.
For that reason, for any process that asks for RAM, the OS allocated
backing swap space that is equal to the amount requested, and allocates it
even before it grants the RAM request. The allocated swap space
is not necessarily allocated as specific disk sectors, but the OS
will make sure that enough free space exists in case of need.

The increase you observe means that your DBMS is slowly increasing its
memory size and asking for more RAM. The swap increases accordingly.

To be totally safe, the swap space should equal the RAM size.
The 6 GB you allocated are far from sufficient.
Increased swap usage should not be alarming.

Comment: Note: Although servers can go years without a reboot, an occasional reboot may help in re-initializing everything.

Comment: I know that Windows uses swap even when RAM is still available. It's the gradual increase of usage over days and weeks which makes me think I have a memory leak of some kind.

"The increase you observe means that your DBMS is slowly increasing its memory size and asking for more RAM."
That's definitely not true. DBMS gets very quickly to the max setting and stays there. The swap usage also didn't drop when I restarted the DBMS service (RAM usage did), so the swap usage is probably not connected to DBMS.

Swap size is 24 GB. 6 GB of RAM are reserved for OS and other services, rest - DBMS.

Comment: In that case, you do have a memory leak. This can be anything - a driver or some part of Windows. Finding such leaks is all but impossible, and even if found you might not be able to fix Windows. I would in your case increase first the 6 GB and watch. If the increase still happens, one solution would be to schedule a recurring reboot with a suitable frequency, and then you can stop worrying about it.

Comment: @harrymc relevant xkcd : https://xkcd.com/1495/

Comment: -1 the explanation of how swap is used, and that "any" OS "needs" to allocate swap in the same amount of RAM granted seems outright wrong to me. Neither is there any logical need that this must be so for any OS, nor is this what happens on any of the machines I have worked with in the last decades (e.g. Linux, some different 'nices, MacOS, Windows etc.). There may be some unrelated effects which - indirectly - may lead to a similar behaviour (i.e. if the OS implements hibernation-to-disk through swap), but as it stands here for this question,  it seems plain wrong to me.

Comment: @AnoE: Indeed, most mainstream OSes (definitely Linux) *overcommit* memory allocations, so not only does it not limit virtual memory allocation to the amount of swap space, it doesn't even limit it to the amount of RAM+swap you have.  So if every process actually dirtied all their memory, it would have to kill a process (Linux's OOM killer) because it's already returned success from those allocations.  Not sure if Windows does overcommit, but I was very surprised to see this claim about reserving swap when memory is allocated.  (If it did that, it presumably wouldn't need a separate hiberfile)

Comment: The total amount of virtual memory allocation has to be less than the amount of RAM plus the amount of swap. There's no need to allocate swap until it's needed. If you have 32GB RAM and 32GB swap, you can use 64GB of total virtual memory, not 32GB.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you sure?  I can remember complaints about needing more swap space when people increased the amount of memory in their machines, because the OS committed swap space when it allocated virtual memory.  (This is going back decades.)  I'm sure VAX used to do that, and thought Windows did too.  It always seemed sensible to me - the relative cost of the extra disk space was always going to be trivial, and it avoided one possible set of errors.

Comment: "the OS allocated backing swap space that is equal to the amount requested, and allocates it even before it grants the RAM request" Isn't this trivially disproved by the stats OP includes in their question? SQL Server is using 42GB of RAM, which is larger than the entire swap file. Its literally impossible that the OS has allocated equal backing swap space, as you say it does.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: I'm sure about Linux overcommitting by default (it's an option to have it not do that), so allocated size can be greater than total available RAM+swap. But apparently not Windows: ([Will Microsoft Windows 10 overcommit memory?](https://superuser.com/q/1194263)).  Linux never require swap reservation, so total allocated size (of anonymous pages, not backed by files) can be greater than swap alone.  As mbrig points out, the OP's stats pretty trivially rules that out for Windows as well, assuming SQL server's memory allocations aren't all file-backed mappings.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because of:

> when something has been paged out and later read back in, the kernel will not remove it from the page file until either the file is otherwise full or the page in RAM is altered. This way if it needs to page that chunk out again it can do so without having to actually write the pages to disk: the content is already there

from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/305335).

Also from a comment there, [Microsoft recommends](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/ram-virtual-memory-pagefile-management) your swap be large enough that it is only 50-75% used at any given time...which is not a problem here.

Microsoft also recommends (from same link):

> Memory, Pages Output/Sec: This counter shows how many virtual memory pages were written to the pagefile to free RAM page frames for other purposes each second.
>
> This is the best counter to monitor if you suspect that paging is your performance bottleneck. Even if Committed Bytes is greater than the installed RAM, if Pages Output/sec is low or zero most of the time, there is no significant performance problem from insufficient RAM.

Short version: modern OSes are like hoarders. They will only let go of something when forced to (hits some limit and cleans out old stuff, or something changed so it lets go of the out of date copy) basically because it can and *it might be useful some day*...

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good thing, a sign of a server OS working properly, using swap space to free up RAM for disk caching.  When the OS first starts up, a bunch of processes are running, but probably never (or rarely) do anything useful because you aren't using those parts of Windows.  Their memory can get paged out, but that only happens gradually when the OS happens to try to reclaim a page.

In low-memory-pressure situations, it's normal for an OS to occasionally pick a random page and see if it's in use, e.g. by marking it invalid (but leaving it in memory so it can quickly wire it back in to the page table for the process that owns it).  If it doesn't get referenced any time soon, the OS might page it out to disk.  (And reclaim it right away, or leave it in RAM until there's a need for more pages for something.)

In Linux, the aggressiveness of this process is set by `vm.swappiness`.  I don't know if Windows has a similar tuning setting.

---

15% of your 24 GB swap file is only 3.6 GB, well under the 6GB size you reserved for everything but the DBMS.

Hopefully, your OS is just paging out dirty pages that never get modified, when some random memory pressure happens to identify such a page.  Such pages are probably common in programs that start up but don't really have anything to do when nothing connects to their services.

The best case is when such a page never even gets read, so it can stay out or RAM.  Then your swap space is doing its job, leaving more RAM available for disk caching and other useful stuff.

But [@user3067860's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1731201/is-gradually-growing-swap-usage-an-indicator-for-a-memory-leak/1731316#1731316) provides another very useful clue: Windows will leave a page in swap space even if it's read back in, so it can be evicted from RAM again for free, without I/O.  It only gets dropped from swap if the page is modified (or freed I guess, e.g. by restarting whatever process owned it).

In most processes that just sit there waiting for someone to talk to them, they probably allocated some memory and wrote to it during startup, but now are just sitting in an event loop waiting for an event that never comes.  Or waking up every few seconds or once a day for something, maybe touching some stack space and a page or two.

But the rest of their pages that they dirtied during startup are not going to be written again ever, and most of them aren't even going to be read if whatever Windows service isn't needed.

**So long-term, we'd expect that most of those pages** (stack and private `.data`/`.bss` pages, and dynamic allocations, "heap") **will eventually get paged out**.  Any that are read but not written will still end up in swap space eventually, but also stay hot in RAM.

And of course there are some things other than your DBMS that *are* doing stuff, like presumably Windows update and logging, so there's some scope for growing the total memory footprint beyond what it was right after boot.

---

This answer is a guess based on how OSes are designed in general, zero experience with actual Windows server tuning.  **There *might* be an actual problem, but it's also quite possible your swap usage will plateau if you leave it alone.**  I'd keep an eye on it, but I wouldn't worry unless your swap usage gets over 6 GB.  If it gets to 12 GiB, then maybe schedule a reboot.

Since restarting your DBMS didn't affect swap usage, it seems those pages weren't from it.  That makes sense; it's actually doing real work and probably writing most of its memory pages frequently.  And your partitioning of physical RAM maybe makes Windows not try to reclaim its pages.